# Do I need PHB3 to use Psionic Power?

Tags: dnd-4e

One of my players wants to play a Monk using the options available in Psionic Power. Do we also need to get PHB3? Or would Psionic Power include most of Monk's base rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHB's cover all the class traits and stats, such as *Proficiencies, Hit Points, Healing Surges, Trained Skills and Class Features*, whilst the *Supplement* books only give you additional options for a class build, like new *Class Features* and powers.
If you don't have the PHB3 you don't have the foundations you need to build a monk, it'd be like buying a brand new body for your car, only to realise you don't even have a car.

There are some online resources though, like [dnd4e wiki](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/D%26D4_Wiki), that give you all the class traits anyway, so no you may not technically need the PHB3, but you can't use **just** the Psionic Power book to create a monk.

Answer (score 3):

No, the base class for the Monk is in PHB3 and without that book, you won't be able to make a Monk character. All of the expansion books really need the base book for their listed classes or you won't be able to play one properly.

(Although if you're strapped for cash, you might be able to cobble something together from just Psionic Power, but it probably won't be pretty because you'll be missing some parts of the class)

Answer (score 3):

The basic details of the Monk class are in PHB3, if you want to play the monk you should probably have a copy of that book in addition to Psionic Power (as, for instance, the basic at-wills/encounters/dailies would be listed in PHB3 rather than PP).

However, if I could recommend a third way. The DDI subscription service from WOTC is still active and will take new subscribers. A year costs about as much as both of the books you're talking about buying and you gain access to the full library of 4e rules content via the compendium, and all the available character options via the character builder. You'll find the time and effort saved in character construction and rules lookup from the character builder and compendium pay for themselves several fold.